# Django doesn't save all modelform fields in database

Tags: django

I customized the default django user model to make email required and username optional. I have a form for users to enter info and create an account. They enter email, first name, last name, password, confirmation password and check the terms/conditions box. All of these fields are required.

In my view, I validate and clean the data and save the user to the database. This was working with a SQLite database and default project layout via the admin tool. Then I decided to use the project layout recommended in two scoops of django. I got the site working again except when I submit a user signup form, it saves the user in the database with an email and password but it doesn't save the first name or last name.

I confirmed that first name and last name are being passed to the view. This makes sense because it was working previously. Maybe there's a setting somewhere that needs updating after the project layout change? I'm really not sure what's happening because it's saving user info to the database, just not all the user info.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! This is my first real django project and I'm stumped right now.

---

from views.py:

```
def signup(request):
    """
    signup page: form to collect user info if they want to sign up
    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(email=email,
                                                username=username,
                                                first_name=first_name,
                                                last_name=last_name,
                                                password=password)
            new_user.save()
            login(request=request, user=new_user)
            #redirect
            return redirect('construction')
        else:
            # Append css error class to each field that has errors
            for field in form.errors:
                if field == '__all__':
                    continue
                form[field].field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' field-error'
    else:
        form = UserForm()

    return render(
        request,
        'signup.html',
        context={'form': form}
    )
```

from models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()
    username = models.CharField(_('username'),
                                max_length=50,
                                unique=False,
                                help_text=_('Optional. 50 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
                                validators=[username_validator],
                                blank=True,
                                null=True)

    email=models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, blank=False, error_messages={
        'unique': _("A user with that email address already exists")
    })

    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=50, blank=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    # REQUIRED_FIELDS should not include the USERNAME_FIELD or password since these will always be prompted for,
    # per the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = UserManager()
```

from forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control",
                                                                 "placeholder": "Password",
                                                                 "required": "required"}))
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control",
                                                                         "placeholder": "Confirm",
                                                                         "required": "required"}))
    terms_conditions = forms.BooleanField(required=True,
                                          initial=False,
                                          widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={"class": "form-check-input",
                                                                            "type": "checkbox",
                                                                            "id": "invalidCheck",
                                                                            "required": "required"}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "email")
        widgets = {
            "first_name": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control",
                                                 "placeholder": "First",
                                                 "required": "required"}),
            "last_name": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control",
                                                 "placeholder": "Last",
                                                 "required": "required"}),
            "email": forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class": "form-control",
                                            "placeholder": "Email",
                                            "required": "required"}),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()

        #check that passwords are the same
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("password and confirmation password do not match")

        terms_agreement = cleaned_data.get("terms_conditions")
        print("Terms + conditions value: " + str(terms_agreement))
```

Comment: make sure the `clean` method in model form return the final cleaned_data

Comment: Good catch. However, I added a 'return cleaned_data' and it's still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. I'll post the problem in case this helps anyone else.

From my models.py: I changed the _create_user call to take 'first_name' and 'last_name' but I forgot to add those fields to the `user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)` statement

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, username, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given email, first name, last name, username, and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email is required')
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError('First name is required')
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError('Last name is required')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Password is required')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, username=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, first_name, last_name, username, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, username=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, first_name, last_name, username, password, **extra_fields)
```